# Why is the atmospheric pressure under a roof and on open land the same?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, atmospheric-science

If someone stands on the ground exposed to the open sky the atmospheric pressure experianced by him will be the same as someone under a roof (which is not part of a sealed box), this is very intuitive but can someone prove this without using method of contradiction.

By method of contradiction i am refering to the proof which says, If the Atmospheric Pressure under a roof is lower then air wil flow to the area of low pressure, but since this does not happen the pressure is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When facing unintuitive phenomena with fluids, I find that if often helps to summon up the picture of vibrating molecules, which are what actually make it up. This may require crude simplifications, but it often helps me understand more directly such phenomena.

So imagine the molecules of air as identical balls that bounce randomly against each other and against every surface they encounter such as that roof. The key here is that, on average, these balls do not lose energy when bouncing, such as it happens with the more familiar everyday hard balls, such as glass marbles. Nonetheless, it is not too hard to imagine those same bounces without the progressive loss of energy after every bounce. As long as the temperature stays the same (it is a measure of the kinetic energy of the vibrating particles), the average energy of each particle is conserved.

The particles will tend to be pushed under the roof and, because the room is not tightly sealed and because the bouncing is so energetic (imagine the particles bouncing extremely fast), the space under the roof will be full of marbles bouncing just as angrily as they do on top of the roof. Now, the 'weight' of the atmosphere that was hard to picture flowing in and then up to push on the roof from below, is actually the result of a myriad impacts under the roof. Those impacts apply small forces that last for only an instant, but such that when summing them all up, the total average force looks stable and quite considerable.

So, if the image of marbles bouncing just as quickly on top and beneath the roof is not too hard to imagine, then you will intuitively understand why the pressure must not be any different. Once all those bouncy particles leak into the room, they will keep bouncing and, thus, pushing. If you still have trouble visualising it, I recommend you to google for molecular dynamics simulations, such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cl7mutMHI0U)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the wonderful annswer.It helped me a lot to visualise the ''weight'' of the atmosphere. Just a small doubt by your answer can i safely presume that the pressure exerted by gases primarily depends on their density and not on their weight? I have a feeling this explanation will not work if we consider denser fluids such as water.

Comment: @nagaram It works the same! The density results from the weight (the column of atmosphere pressing down on it), which keeps the molecules pressed more tightly.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are asking a physics question rather than a mathematics question, a watertight logical proof is impossible. Physical phenomena can be explained by reference to other phenomena, and often by reference to underlying principles and laws, but they are always contingent facts. Indeed, one can imagine circumstances where the pressure under a roof is *not* the same as in the open air - if the roof is part of a hermetically sealed box, for example, or if the properties of the atmosphere were such that pressure did *not* act equally in all directions.

Also, you seem to be looking for an explanation that avoids using the very reason for the phenomena. This is like asking someone to explain why the sky is blue but without mentioning the scattering of light. Very difficult.

Comment: Hmm if a logical proof is not possible without mathemetics, then i would like a proof using physical phenomenon or anything other than the method of contradiction.

Comment: Nice notes about reverse situation, indeed it there's some kind of turbulence or strong winds near roof, which according to Bernoulli's principle will change pressure distribution, then these pair or locations will not have same pressure due to air flow differences.

Comment: @nagaram Well, you could use an energy argument. A state where there is a pressure difference has a higher energy than an equal pressure state, and systems generally move towards a state of lower energy when they can.

Answer (score 0):

in liquids and gases pressure at one hight always goes in every direction, so any differences are vanishing in short time.

Comment: That's what the OP calls '*method of contradiction*'.